# Django change format for datetime in database

Tags: django-models

Can someone give a tips. How can i control format datetime for saving in db for my datetimefield with auto_now. It is saving in form YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM but i need that in database my entry looks like this 10/14/2015 1:34:54 AM.

Comment: Datetime in your database is depending on the db provider and has 2 parts: stored value and presentation value (format). The format is a question of displaying the value, not about how to store it. You should care  for the display format only in the UI (Web, Mobile/Desktop client).

Comment: What database are you using and how are you seeing the form? As Roba commented, it is as simple as figuring out your DB's date formatting function if you're displaying from a SQL CLI or GUI.

Comment: I'm using MySQL. And i need db format of date (it has long pre-story for that), but i bypassed this demand by defining my datetime field as charfield.

Comment: Wasn't best solution. Now i'm getting wrong sorting(sorting as a string). Define custom method to which convert string to date, and add it to list display. Sorting unable now. I know i can define admin_order_field attr for my method. But can it sort not by field but by its value?